# How to open "Project Structure page" in multiple instances of intellij IDE at the same time

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to compare project structure of 2 different projects in IntelliJ. I can open 2 projects in 2 different IntelliJ windows correctly.I then open Project structure in one IntelliJ window which is a modal dialog . Unfortunately, the modal dialog blocks me from accessing the second project which is opened in difference IntelliJ IDE.

Is there a way for me to dissociate 2 instances of intelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible if you run multiple frames in the same instance, see the corresponding issue and the linked issues:

- [IDEABKL-6069](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6069) Per project/frame modality

You can run 2 instances in different JVMs by changing the locations of `config`/`system`/`plugins` directories as [described in the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181). This way you will have 2 IDEA copies on your disk running in the different JVMs.

Comment: Thanks..... it was hard for me to believe that its a single OS process. Chrome does multiple processes. But, I guess this was a very old decision architectural decision for IDEA